# Newton Raphson really slow loop and derivative function's root?

Tags: matlab

I wrote this code for the Newton Raphson Method and I have a problem:

Firstly:

```
function [k] = ex2_b(a,b,e)

clc

syms x;

df= @(x) diff(exp((sin(x))^3) + x^6 - 2*(x^4) - (x^3) - 1);
df2 =@(x) diff(df);
```

I want to find if df and df2 have roots between -2 and 2. I couldn't figure out how to work with fzero. Is there another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to solve the function f'(x)=0 or just want to know whether there exists roots between [-2,2]? Do not use `diff` in `fzero`. Actually it is not that difficult to get the f'(x):

```
df= @(x) (3*sin(x).^2.*cos(x).*exp((sin(x)).^3) + 5*x.^5 - 8*(x.^3) - (3*x.^2) );
fzero(df,-2)
>>-1.0634
fzero(df,2)
>>1.3895
```

f'(x) has roots between [-2,2].

f''(x) is a little bit complicated but still not tough if you change `sin(x).^2` into `1-cos(x).^2`.

If you just want to check the existence of the roots, you can plot the curve:

```
df= @(x) diff(exp((sin(x)).^3) + x.^6 - 2*(x.^4) - (x.^3) - 1);
x=[-3:0.1:3];
plot(x(2:end),df(x))
```

and,

```
df2= @(x) diff(3*sin(x).^2.*cos(x).*exp((sin(x)).^3) + 5*x.^5 - 8*(x.^3) - (3*x.^2) );
x=[-1:0.01:1];
plot(x(2:end),df2(x))
```

or just,

```
plot(x(3:end),diff(df(x)))
```

Both `df` and `df2` have roots in [-2,2].